# Show a select with only one option

Tags: laravel

```html
@if(auth()->user()->type == 'admin')
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('course_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="user_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">User</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="user_id" name="user_id">
             <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select user</option>
         @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $user }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! $errors->first('course_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
@else
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('course_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="user_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">User</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" name="user_id" type="text" id="user_id" value="{{ old('user_id', optional($->id)) }}" minlength="1" placeholder="Enter name here...">

        {!! $errors->first('course_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

I´ve got a problem in my form.blade.php I have a controller for RegisteredCourses, and this one is shared between admin and student roles. In the blade, I use and If/else directive to filter between both roles. In case that the user is an administrator, several options are displayed. By the other hand, in case that the user is an student, I only need one option in the select, the name of the student authenticated I just want to show his name, not the whole users names from database.

I choose the select because I can shown the name and store the user_id because is an integer. I do not want to type the number of the id by hand.

I am not really sure if it´s the best idea to filter different blades in Laravel. Anyone have any suggestions?

Please, I need something as simple as possible, because my knowledge in Laravel is limited.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```html
@if(auth()->user()->type == 'admin')

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('course_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="user_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">User</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="user_id" name="user_id">
             <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select user</option>
         @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $user }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! $errors->first('course_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

@else

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('course_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="user_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">User</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="user_id" name="user_id">
                  <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select user</option>
            @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
                    @if ($key == Auth::user()->id)
                        <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse)->user_id) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                            {{ $user }}
                        </option>
                    @endif  
            @endforeach
        </select>
    
            {!! $errors->first('course_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    
@endif
```

Finally, I needed to check if $key was equal to Auth::user()->id and I got only one option.

I hope this can be useful for someone.

Thanks.